# Using sed and regex to capture last part of url

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm trying to make sed match the last part of a url and output just that. For example:

`echo "http://randomurl/suburl/file.mp3" | sed (expression)`

should give the output:

`file.mp3`

So far I've tried `sed 's|\([^/]+mp3\)$|\1|g'` but it just outputs the whole url. Maybe there's something I'm not seeing here but anyways, help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this works:

```
 echo "http://randomurl/suburl/file.mp3" | sed 's#.*/##'
```

Comment: could you elaborate on what it does?

Comment: in rule `'s#.*/##'`, first `#` means set `#` as separation character, so the whole rule means replace `.*/` to empty. same rule  `echo "http://randomurl/suburl/file.mp3" | sed 's/.*\///'`

Answer (score 9):

`basename` is your good friend.

```
> basename "http://randomurl/suburl/file.mp3"
=> file.mp3
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
$ echo "http://randomurl/suburl/file.mp3" | sed -r 's|.*/(.*)$|\1|'
file.mp3
```

where:

- `|` has been used instead of `/` to separate the arguments of the `s` command.
- Everything is matched and replaced with whatever if found after the last `/`.

Edit: You could also use bash [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSOREX2) capabilities:

```
$ url="http://randomurl/suburl/file.mp3"
$ echo ${url##*/}
file.mp3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'http://randomurl/suburl/file.mp3' | grep -oP '[^/\n]+$'
```

Here's another solution using `grep`.